# How to configure a Filter web part to filter two lists at the same time?

Tags: filter

I have two list on the same page, they both have the same Column.
I need to add a filter to sort these both lists at the same time via this same column.

Comment: Some details, one list has a Column (Single Line of Text), and the second list has a lookup to this Column. So the are not the very same.